# convert click to page load jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery and it loads when you click the button but I want it to load the functions when the page is loaded.

```
      $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function() {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        });

 $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

I've tried using this but it doesnt work:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

Comment: you only use one $(document).ready() and place everything inside. Also what version of jQuery is this? isn't .live deprecated?

Comment: not sure. This is where I found the code: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx

Comment: Live is in fact [removed as of version 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/category/removed/#post-409).

Comment: where is your click event

Comment: What do you expect `$(this).closest("tr")` to refer to when the page is loading? You haven't clicked on anything, so there's no useful `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[src*=plus]").closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + 
   $("[src*=plus]").next().html() + "</td></tr>")
    $("[src*=plus]").attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    $("[src*=plus]").attr("src", "images/plus.png");
    $("[src*=plus]").closest("tr").next().remove();
});
```

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Done that. Thanks for the input

Comment: @FurquanKhan great will remove my comment :)